# Can anyone explain join behavior with Null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

According to my knowledge, Null is not comparable with anything. But in below example getting result in different way. Can someone help me to understand?

```
Create table t1 (c1 number);

 Insert into T1(C1) Values(1);
 Insert into T1(C1) Values(NULL);
 Insert into T1(C1) Values(1);
 Insert into T1(C1) Values(NULL);
 Insert into T1(C1) Values(1);

create table t2 (c2 number);

 Insert into T2(C2) Values(1);
 Insert into T2(C2) Values(NULL);
 Insert into T2(C2) Values(1);
 Insert into T2(C2) Values(NULL);
 Insert into T2(C2) Values(1);
 Insert into T2(C2) Values(NULL);
 Insert into T2(C2) Values(1);

 select * from t1;

1
NULL
1
NULL
1

select * from t2

1
NULL
1
NULL
1
NULL
1
select * from t1 inner join t2 on(t1.c1=t2.c2);

C1   C2
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    1
```

Please find the attached image for result set.

Comment: The output contains 12 rows because  each of 3 not null `t1` rows match each of 4 `t2` not null rows  , 1=1.

Comment: Hi Serg, Thanks for the response. So, each '1' is mapping with other '1' in second table. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Please, clarify what is the "different way" and what explanation you expect